# How do I specify the multiple enums in the parameterized constructor?

Tags: java

I have to specify the multiple enums in the parameterized constructor. I built in the following way. I am not sure, this is the right approach or not. Please guide.

```
public final class WageCalculator {

    public WageCalculator(final WeekDays day) {
        //TO-DO
    }

    public WageCalculator(final WeekDays day1, final WeekDays day2) {
        //TO-DO
    }

    public enum WeekDays {

        MON("MONDAY"), TUE("TUESDAY"), WED("WEDNESDAY"), THU("THURSDAY"), FRIDAY("FRI"), SAT("SATURDAY"), SUN("SUNDAY");

        private final String value;

        private WeekDays(final String dayStr) {
            this.value = dayStr;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Pattern.quote(value);
        }
    }
}
```

then, I modified the parameterized constructor with List. Does this add an flexibility here instead of passing all the enum values in the constructor?

```
private final List<WeekDays> days;

    public WageCalculator(final List<WeekDays> day) {
        days = day;
    }

    public WageCalculator(final WeekDays day) {
        days = new ArrayList<>();
        days.add(day);
    }
```

Comment: I'd probably not have WeekDay(s) as object state >_< That said, using a collection is often much more appropriate than v1,v2,..vn variables/parameters. Java also supports ["vararg" parameters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-arguments-varargs-in-java/), which may make the call simpler.

Comment: What are you eventually trying to do with the `days` field?

Comment: Perform a calculation based on the day's enum value.

Comment: I agree with user2864740 comment. makes sense for me. Thank you. Today I learned this.

Comment: Try using an EnumSet so you do not get duplicate values

Answer (score 2):

I would use varargs:

```
private final List<WeekDays> days;

public WageCalculator(WeekDays... days) {
    this.days = Arrays.asList(days);
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
WageCalculator standard = new WageCalculator(MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI);
```

Also, you should name your enum `WeekDay` (singular, not `WeekDays`) because the name of the enum class is what *each instance* is, not the name of the group of instances.

You should probably use a Set rather than a List for the days, because it doesn't make sense to have the same day twice in a working week.

---

As an aside, even though many do it and many frameworks assume it, it's an antipattern to name tables in the plural, eg `users` for the same reason - the table should be the name of the *row* (ie instances), not the collection of rows.